# Submit large amount of text to springboot controller

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot

I have a springboot application that offers to edit very big configuration files (about 40k lines). One part of the application handles direct editing of the files in a .js text editor. However, the changes made there cannot be tracked and uploaded to the backend individually meaning that I have to update the whole configuration for every change.

Now in the test phase I really naively just sent the whole thing as a string via html form since we only worked with small files. Now that the files are bigger that causes the String parameter in the controller method on the backend to be `Null`.

Html code:

```
<form action="/someUrl" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="editorText" name="editorText" />
    <input class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="margin-top: 15px;" type="submit" th:value="#{mSave}"/>
</form>
```

Now my Question would be how can I send a large amount of text reliably to a spring controller via html ? 
If thats of any help, I'm using the [QuillJS](https://quilljs.com/) Text Editor. The submited input is just updated with every change made like this:

```
document.getElementById("editor").value = quill.getText();
```

And the spring controller in the backend looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/someUrl", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String changeInEditor(Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, @RequestParam("editorText") String editorText) {


//editorText is Null
//...
}
```

Really appreciate any hint/help!

Edit 1: Added the @RequestParam and RequestMethod

Comment: Yeah it still works fine with smaller files.
This causes a `org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'editorText' is not present` exception. I think the problem is that the controller wants to access the param before the transfer has succeeded or is that not possible?

Comment: Yes I did the naming correctly, both the `@RequestParam` and the input tag is called `editorText`. But also with the new controller signature it raises the above mentioned exception. (Edited signature in the question above)

Comment: Then I don't know. Final think, set your getElementId to `.getElementById("editorText")`

Comment: Sadly that's also not the problem, checked the naming twice now and it still works for the smaller files. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Since you are using `@RequestParam("editorText")` in your controller method, then you should have one input type attribute in DOM or form which name is `editorText`. Again what do mean by smaller file? This is a nothing but a text field `[not a file/multipart type]`. How many text do you want to sent, this should not be a problem with a post request.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna I have a form like mentioned in the html code in the question. I tried it with 3 different filesizes. One only containing about 100 chars, one with a few thousand chars (for these all works fine, meaning that the string in the Controller is set). Only for the last file (> 40k lines) it doesnt work. Do you think sending it via `File, Multipart file` would do the trick ?

Comment: You can try that using Spring Multipart file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upload it as a multipart file. Here is a link for reference.

[How to upload file in spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44128195/how-to-upload-file-in-spring)