# How to get string from form-data values in post method Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, form-data, http-request-parameters

I'm trying to get string value from form-data in the Post method in Spring.

I'm getting a bad request error.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@RequestMapping(value = "/formdataValueGet", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> formdataValueGet(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("file") String file) throws Exception{
    System.out.println("Api hit file upload");
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    System.out.println("Map issue");
    try{
    params.put("error", "Failed to make payment");
    return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(params, HttpStatus.OK);
    }catch(Exception ae){
        params.put("error", "Failed to make payment");
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(params, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload file in spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44128195/how-to-upload-file-in-spring)

Comment: I added  consumes = {"multipart/form-data"}. Actually I don't want to get a file from form-data. I want to get a string from the form-data type.

Comment: Does it work with that?

Comment: No, it still returning bad request error code 400

Comment: What about using `@ModelAttribute` instead of `@RequestParam`?